#   unbounded power series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, reference-request

I want a reference to the literature of a power series convergent in the whole CLOSED 
  unit disk,but unbounded there.

Answer (score 3):

An example of such a series is given in:

> W. Sierpiński "Sur une série potentielle qui, étant convergente en tout point de son cercle de convergence, représente sur ce cercle une fonction discontinue" Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo, Volume 41, Issue 1, pp. 187-190

I learned about this from Julien Melleray in an answer to the following question [Does a power series converging everywhere on its circle of convergence define a continuous function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110345/does-a-power-series-converging-everywhere-on-its-circle-of-convergence-define-a-c) (which seems very close but then not the same as this one).

Also the answer of George Lowther there is very interesting.

To avoid potential confusion let me stress that while the title of the paper talks about discontinous, the function constructed  by  Sierpiński is actually unbounded (and thus discontinous).

Comment:  I'm a novice "overflow" user and highly computer illiterate,but wish to heartily thank this respondent for such a complete answer to my 
question,with detailed literature reference. I "knew of" the Sierpinski paper but had indeed been misled by its title into not
examining it. Now I have and it's beautiful,clear and ingenious. More
egg on my face: The review in the old JAHRBUCH (which I'd long ago
seen) mentions the unboundedness! Thanks again.
                                                   Bob Burckel

Comment: You are very welcome!